# how to know the subclass of mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A{

    private long id;
}

@Entity
public class B extends A{

    private String bProperty;
}

@Entity
public class C extends A{

    private String cProperty;
}

@Entity
public class Person{

    @OneToMany
    private Set<A> a;
}
```

when I use person.getVehicles

How can I know the A is B or C?

I'm using instanceof to check and cast it to get bProperty or cProperty.

Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only safe way is to use a polymorphic method. Even instanceof will not work because the instance might actually be a proxy, i.e. a subclass of A that is neither a B or a C, but delegates to a B or a C.

```
public class A{
    private long id;

    public abstract boolean isB();
    public abstract boolean isC();
    public abstract String getBProperty();
    public abstract String getCProperty();
}

public class B extends A{
    private String bProperty;

    public boolean isB() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isC() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getBProperty() {
        return bProperty;
    }

    public String getCProperty() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("I'm not a C");
    }
}
```

To be cleaner, try using the visitor pattern. I've written a [blog post](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2012/12/27/visitor-pattern-et-jpa/) about it. It's in French, but it should be easily translatable.

Comment: Nice site JB. Luckily I didn't struggle with French throughout my primary/highschool for nothing. It's Return-Of-Investment time.